# What are the technical reasons for the warning in the new bulk edit in Shopware 6.4.5.0?

Tags: bulk, shopware

Shopware 6.4.5.0 now has bulk edit.

When applying changes there is a scary warning popup.

[image: Warning]

I had a look at the network tab when changing 2 products, and there is only a single call too the sync-endpoint:

[image: Request]

So I am actually still wondering why this warning is there and if it is safe to use bulk edit, for example on unstable connections (I guess closing the browser tab or a unstable connection would have similar results?)

1. What are the technical reasons behind this message?
2. Shall we only not close the browser or will a breaking connection also cause problems?
3. Can the bulk edit be made safer (for example by pushing the changes into the background-queue and execute it without the need for an active browser connection)?

Comment: I'm asking the question internally.

Comment: You don't see the danger in stopping an edit process on a big batch of files? It's the same danger as stopping an edit process in the middle of running on a single file... but multiplied. Regarding a network connection: that would be the same as closing the browser tab, basically, so don't do it.

Comment: Oh, I see the danger but I am wondering why we have to present users which such warnings and don't make it more robust. Nobody wants to destroy there shops. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk edit requests are executed via JavaScript. The reason you only see one request is because you are editing fewer than 50 entities, which is the chunk size for the request; ref. [`onSave()` method](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ad3ef04d52c63cd79646011c4abdec9eeaf3b21c/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-bulk-edit/page/sw-bulk-edit-product/index.js#L702):

```js
        async onSave() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.onProcessData();

            const payloadChunks = chunk(this.selectedIds, 50);

            const requests = payloadChunks.map(payload => {
                return this.bulkEditApiFactory.getHandler('product')
                    .bulkEdit(payload, this.bulkEditSelected);
            });

            this.bulkEditSelected = [];

            return Promise.all(requests)
                .then(response => {
                    const isSuccessful = response.every(item => item.success === true);
                    this.processStatus = isSuccessful ? 'success' : 'fail';
                }).catch(() => {
                    this.processStatus = 'fail';
                }).finally(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
        },
```

h/t to my colleague David Neustadt for pointing out the chunking.

Comment: Thanks. Still I believe it will scare away some users. I think it would be better to do the chunking server side in a queue jobs, and inform the users "batch editing happens in the background, we will notify you when done."

Comment: Agree on both points. I believe we are looking to adjust the language in the near term. Job queues are a slightly larger scope ;-)